# Share /var/www/ on Virtual Box CentOS 6.3 VM with Windows 7

Tags: centos, windows-7, network-shares

I would like the ability to share /var/www/ on Virtual Box CentOS 6.3 VM with Windows 7 so I can:

- Browse file tree's in my IDE.
- Save changes without permissions conflicts during development.

I understand a place to start is in the VM's Shared Folders tab in Virtual Box. I have not been much further than that nor understand how to build the bridge I am looking for.

Also note that I do not have a desktop environment set up on my CentOS guest. I would need to do everthing from shell. This is part of the difficulty that I am having becuase several guides I've consulted are using GUI applications.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows 7:

1. Start -> Run -> compmgmt.msc
2. Shares -> Make New Share

### CentOS 6.3

```
# yum install samba-client
# yum install cifs-utils
# nano /etc/fstab
```

**Add**

```
\\192.168.1.1\nameOfWindowsShare /var/www/html cifs username=myWindowsUsername,password=myWindowsPassword 0 0
```

**Restart**

```
# mount -a
```

Comment: Althoguh this share works initially, after abotu 30 minuts I am getting hangs. At this point I am unable to access the folder via Windows or CentOS and the process hangs.

Comment: I tried this and it killed my apache service, It seems when I mount in anything under /var/www/ it kills apache and stops it from being restarted still looking at why though but it fires an error on the "Document Root =" line of httpd.conf